# How to define a variable string range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to count the number of columns within a variable range and use the address of the last column to form part of defined range. Once I have defined the range I will want to input a formula. Can anyone please help?

Example

```
Dim lastcolumn as string

Lastcolumn = sheet("test").range("a1").end(xltoright).column

Sheets("test").range("b1:" & lastcolumn).select

Selection.formula = "myformula"
```

Comment: something like `sheet("test").range("a1").end(xltoright).formula="xyz"` should do it I think, last column would be an integer.   or maybe `cells(sheet("test").range("a1").end(xltoRight),1).formula`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get rid of `lastColumn` calculation (and bothering about its type...)

```
With Sheets("test")
    .Range("B1", .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Formula = "myformula"
End With
```

Answer (score 4):

The column returns a number not a cell so you need to provide more info.  You will need to use `Cells()`.

Also avoid using Select it slows down the code:

```
Dim lastcolumn as Long

Lastcolumn = sheets("test").range("a1").end(xltoright).column

Sheets("test").range("b1",Sheets("test").Cells(1,lastcolumn)).formula ="myformula"
```

Comment: Beat me to it - Nice answer! - I'd just maybe change lastcolumn to an integer.

Comment: Why not declare and treat `lastcolumn ` as the integer that it is? (btw, it is **Sheets**, not Sheet).

Comment: @Jeeped got tied up in the other part missed that it was a string not a Integer/Long.

Comment: @Jeeped that's what i get by trying to be like you and just correct the code directly in the answer space and not through VBE.

Comment: **LOL** - Almost *every* time I try to correct code without the VBE I get bitten in the a$$! You are not following my posts' edit history of corrections! (btw, big day tomorrow... fingers crossed)

Comment: Cheers guys. This works for me yet is it at all possible to identify the lastcolumn as a string alphabetic character?